# Python Filter only nulls in three columns and apply values from different columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have below data set in df dataframe 3 dates for C_ and 3 dates for S_

```
C_Sub_Date C_Review_Date C_Approved_Date  S_Sub_Date S_Review_Date S_Approved_Date
1/2/2019   1/2/2019         1/2/2019       1/2/2019    1/2/2019       1/2/2019  
   Null      Null             Null         3/2/2020    3/2/2020       3/2/2020
   Null   3/4/2021          3/4/2021       3/4/2021    3/4/2021       3/4/2021
```

> Condition = When all three dates for C is null then I want to use the
> dates in S columns

So expected output is

```
C_Sub_Date C_Review_Date C_Approved_Date  S_Sub_Date S_Review_Date S_Approved_Date
1/2/2019   1/2/2019         1/2/2019       1/2/2019    1/2/2019       1/2/2019  
3/2/2020   3/2/2020         3/2/2020       3/2/2020    3/2/2020       3/2/2020
   Null   3/4/2021          3/4/2021       3/4/2021    3/4/2021       3/4/2021
```

If you note above, I did not update the row 3 because it does not meet the condition of all three under C being blank.

I thought to create a mask of nulls and apply the values in new dataframe

```
# Create a mask of the records with all three columns to null
mask = (df['C_Sub_Date'].isnull() & df['C_Review_Date'].isnull() & df['C_Approved_Date'].isnull())

#Select the records with all three columns to null
df_update = df[mask]

# Update the columns with the values from df_updated
df.loc[mask, 'C_Sub_Date'] = df_update['S_Sub_Date']
df.loc[mask, 'C_Review_Date'] = df_update['S_Review_Date']
df.loc[mask, 'C_Approved_Date'] = df_update['S_Approved_Date']
```

*The above is not working because its unable to find 'S_Sub_Date'*

**But is my approach right? Can you please guide?**

Answer (score 0):

I updated in the same dataframe and it worked

```
# Create a mask of the records with all three columns to null
mask = (df['C_Sub_Date'].isnull() & df['C_Review_Date'].isnull() & df['C_Approved_Date'].isnull())


# Update the columns with the values from df_updated
df.loc[mask, 'C_Sub_Date'] = df['S_Sub_Date']
df.loc[mask, 'C_Review_Date'] = df['S_Review_Date']
df.loc[mask, 'C_Approved_Date'] = df['S_Approved_Date']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this without needing the exact names of the `C_` and `S_` columns (they just need to correspond). The `C_` and `S_` columns can be in a different order, and at any place within the `df`. In addition, some `C_` columns may have no `S_` equivalent, and vice-versa.

We provide both a *fluent expression* (leaving `df` unmodified --favored), as well as an *in-place version* (that modifies the original `df`).

```py
cdf = df.filter(regex='^C_')
sdf = df.filter(regex='^S_')
mask = cdf.isna().all(axis=1)
subst = sdf.rename(columns=lambda name: f'C_{name[2:]}')

# fluent expression
newdf = df.assign(**dict(cdf.where(~mask, subst)))

>>> newdf
  C_Sub_Date C_Review_Date C_Approved_Date S_Sub_Date S_Review_Date S_Approved_Date
0 2019-01-02    2019-01-02      2019-01-02 2019-01-02    2019-01-02      2019-01-02
1 2020-03-02    2020-03-02      2020-03-02 2020-03-02    2020-03-02      2020-03-02
2        NaT    2021-03-04      2021-03-04 2021-03-04    2021-03-04      2021-03-04

# in-place expression (discouraged)
df.loc[mask, subst.columns] = subst.loc[mask]
```

Note: to make your example reproducible, here is the setup code. It ensures all values are `Timestamp`s:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'C_Sub_Date': ['2019-01-02', '', ''],
    'C_Review_Date': ['2019-01-02', '', '2021-03-04'],
    'C_Approved_Date': ['2019-01-02', '', '2021-03-04'],
    'S_Sub_Date': ['2019-01-02', '2020-03-02', '2021-03-04'],
    'S_Review_Date': ['2019-01-02', '2020-03-02', '2021-03-04'],
    'S_Approved_Date': ['2019-01-02', '2020-03-02', '2021-03-04'],
}).applymap(pd.to_datetime)
```

#### Different example

To demonstrate the flexibility of the above, here is a different example using `float` values instead of `Timestamp`, and using different columns, some matching, some not:

```py
v = np.arange(3 * 7).reshape(3, -1).astype(float)
v[(1, 2, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 2)] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(
    v, columns=['C_Foo', 'C_Bar', 'C_Babar', 'other',
                'S_Fubar', 'S_Bar', 'S_Foo'])

# after code above to fill C columns with corresponding
# S columns where all C columns are nan:

>>> newdf
   C_Foo  C_Bar  C_Babar  other  S_Fubar  S_Bar  S_Foo
0    0.0    1.0      2.0    3.0      4.0    5.0    6.0
1   13.0   12.0      NaN   10.0     11.0   12.0   13.0
2    NaN   15.0     16.0   17.0     18.0   19.0   20.0
```

Notice how `C_Babar`, having no `S_` equivalent, is left unchanged. The extra column, `other`, is also left alone. And the `Foo`, `Bar` columns are in a different order, but that order is respected.

Note that, in this example, the in-place version would add a new `'C_Fubar'` column. We could avoid this with a slightly more complex expression, but, as I said, I would discourage in-place operations anyway.